# Is there a way to rerun a job as and when it fails during a GitHub Actions workflow?

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a workflow that reuses several other workflows in parallel. Many of these are flakey and need to be rerun. However, I am losing a lot of time as I need to wait for all the jobs to complete, and for the workflow to fail before I am able to "rerun failed jobs". Is there any workaround for this?

I have tried failing the main workflow when a job fails, but this feels counter productive to running multiple workflows in parallel. Rerunning failed jobs automatically is also something I considered, but this ended up in a lot of wasted time as sometimes jobs fail due to genuine reasons and need not be rerun

Comment: As stated in the (blog post](https://github.blog/2022-03-16-save-time-partial-re-runs-github-actions/), you can already re-run specific jobs when they fail. However it seems you need the whole workflow run to stop before being able to do it.